# How to get music from System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer resources? In a wpf application, online music player?

Tags: wpf, caching, audio, resources, download

I was doing a wpf music player, use the system.windows.media namespace mediaPlayer control. In my opinion, it can play music files on the machine can also play online with other online music. When it is playing online music, download it first and then buffer some, play some. Finally, I think this music sounds good, want to download. My question is, since it has been played, then this file is not already been downloaded to the local out? If so, how can I get to it?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think this is supported because of digital right management concerns. Its possible that who ever is owning the content the user is playing only wants it to be streamed. Internally though, MediaPlayer most likely keeps a buffer for seeking through content, but its probbly not saved to disk.

That said, if you have an uri, you could use that to download the content localy and then play it, but im unsure how that would work with streaming (starting to download content, and meanwhile asking mediaplayer to play the uri to that local file)